# How to denote the set of binary relations of which a particular ordered pair is a member?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, category-theory, relations, relation-algebra

Given a universe $U$ and two subsets $S$ and $T$ (also, both members of $U$), what is the name given to denote the set of all binary relations in $U$ where the ordered pair $(S,T)$ is a member?

The concept I'm trying to describe is similar to $Hom(S,T)$ in a category of sets, but where as $Hom(S,T)$ is a category of all morphisms from $S$ to $T$, the concept I am targeting is: (1) limited in scope to sets; and (2) looking for all the morphisms for which $(S,T)$ are associated instead of for the morphisms from $S$ to $T$.

Comment: What is the problem with $\{(S,T): S,T \in \mathcal{P}(U)\}$ ?